# Python date format?

Tags: python, date

I'm really hoping you can help me with this.  I have a date outputted by a python program that I need to be able to access in another program.

The problem is that I have no idea how this date is formatted:

```
Format               Date
129893779638930000 - 2012-08-13 17:32:43
```

It is both date and time, and I'm really hoping somebody recognizes what format it is in, as I don't know python very well.  Bonus points if you can show me how to convert it to a unix timestamp.

EDIT:
The program that does this is a component for Foobar2000 (an extension for a music program).  The component is shown here: http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_playcount, and it is the XML export feature that generates the odd date/timestamp.

Comment: Do you mean that 129893678626216000 should decode to 2012-08-13 14:44:22, and you’re trying to find the decoding algorithm?

Comment: Yes, exactly, which is why I know it isn't a variant of the unix timestamp.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the program that outputs it? If not, can you at least hint at what that program is? I don’t know but this could be a domain-specific convention or something.

Comment: Definitely, sorry I didn't think it would be helpful as it is a compiled dll, but again I don't know much about python, it might be decompilable.  It's a component to Foobar2000 - http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_playcount.  The XML export is what uses the odd encoding of date/timestamps

Comment: Another thing, it says somewhere it uses a 64 bit file time "A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)", but I have no clue what that is (not a python guy)

Comment: related: [Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6161776/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`129893678626216000` looks like the unix timestamp in 1e-8 seconds (tens of nanoseconds): `1,298,936,786.262,160,00`. It would represent:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(129893678626216000/1e8)
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28, 23, 46, 26, 262160)
```

**EDIT:** However your information "A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)" tells me to use:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + timedelta(seconds = 129893678626216000/1e7)
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 13, 21, 44, 22, 621599)
```

where you get exactly what you awaited.

You can also convert it directly to unix timestamp (number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC):

```
>>> 129893678626216000 / 1e7 - 11644473600
1344894262.6215992
```

Comment: By doing the division first, you risk running into floating point resolution limits.  Better to do the subtraction first: `(129893678626216000 - 116444736000000000) / 10000000`.

Comment: P.S. converting to the Unix timestamp mathematically rather than bouncing through `datetime` is a good idea, since it eliminates time zone considerations.

Comment: P.S.S Or use timezone-aware epoch.  Note that `utcfromtimestamp` is deprecated since 3.12. See its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) for safer alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [Windows file time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1,
>   1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The system records file times
>   when applications create, access, and write to files. The NTFS file
>   system stores time values in UTC format, so they are not affected by
>   changes in time zone or daylight saving time. The FAT file system
>   stores time values based on the local time of the computer. For
>   example, a file that is saved at 3:00pm PST in Washington is seen as
>   6:00pm EST in New York on an NTFS volume, but it is seen as 3:00pm EST
>   in New York on a FAT volume.

See also [FILETIME Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx).

The important bit is that the time might be both in UTC and local timezone. If there might be FAT filesystem; check whether the plugin reads the filetimes directly from disk without any transformations to find out whether you need take into account local timezone.

For UTC case ([adapting C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161842/4279)):

```
WINDOWS_TICK_INTERVAL  = 100e-9 # 100 nanoseconds intervals
SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH = (datetime(1970, 1, 1) - datetime(1601, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
# -> 11644473600

def WindowsTickToUnixSeconds(windowsTicks):
    return windowsTicks * WINDOWS_TICK_INTERVAL - SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH
```

To convert it to `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime

filetime = 129893779638930000
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(WindowsTickToUnixSeconds(filetime))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f-00:00"))
# -> 2012-08-14 00:32:43.893000-00:00
```

It seems correspond to the time in your question: `2012-08-13 17:32:43-07:00` (maybe PDT).

To handle DST for filetimes in local timezone (from FAT) from the past you might need [pytz library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

All is happy with the world, a filetime is like a unix timestamp but measured from 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601, so subtracting the right amount of seconds and dividing to seconds gives you a unix timestamp, try this: `(FILETIME - 116444736000000000) / 10000000`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the original data was a Windows [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime):

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

And the OP's data of:

```
Format               Date
129893779638930000 - 2012-08-13 17:32:43
```

As of Python 3.12 the recommendation is to use time zone-aware `datetime` to compute UTC offsets.  Display in whatever time zone you like.  The OP's data appears to be displayed as Pacific Time Zone (UTC-8 standard time or UTC-7 daylight savings time):

```py
# May need "pip install -U tzdata" for latest time zone data on some OSes.
import datetime as dt
import zoneinfo as zi  # uses system's time zone data if available, or "tzdata" as fallback.

EPOCH = dt.datetime(1601, 1, 1, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
result = EPOCH + dt.timedelta(seconds=129893779638930000 / 1e7)
print(result.astimezone(tz=zi.ZoneInfo('PST8PDT')))

# Since it is time zone-aware, this is the correct Unix timestamp:
print(result.timestamp())  # seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Output (agrees with OP's number/datetime)

```
2012-08-13 17:32:43.893000-07:00
1344904363.893
```