# How to parse MFT File Record bytes using ctypes and struct?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes, ntfs-mft

Don't know if this is a duplicate, anyway my Google-fu is weak and Google almost never finds anything relevant if I type more than five words.

I am trying to parse Master File Table as located by `"//?/X:/$MFT"`, I know trying to open it directly will raise `PermissionDenied`. Of course I have figured a way to circumvent it. By opening `"//?/X:"` this creates a handle that lets me to read the boot sector, I can then read the MFT from there...

I have already written the code, or at least the vast majority of it, I can already read all of the MFT into primary memory but at this stage the memory usage is high and the information is not well organized. But I have parsed all information I wanted with the help of [this documentation](http://inform.pucp.edu.pe/%7Einf232/Ntfs/ntfs_doc_v0.5/index.html).

You can see my code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289225/python-master-file-table-parser).

As you can see from my code, I use a lot of offsets to slice the bytes into chunks and call corresponding functions to decode these chunks iteratively, I will show you what I mean:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Record_Header_Flags(NamedTuple):
    In_Use: bool
    Directory: bool
    Extension: bool
    Special_Index: bool


class Record_Header(NamedTuple):
    LogFile_Serial: int
    Written: int
    Hardlinks: int
    Flags: Record_Header_Flags
    Record_Size: int
    Base_Record: int
    Base_Writes: int
    Record_ID: int


HEADER_FLAGS = (1, 2, 4, 8)


def parse_signed_little_endian(data: bytes) -> int:
    return (
        -1 * (1 + sum((b ^ 0xFF) * (1 << i * 8) for i, b in enumerate(data)))
        if data[-1] & 128
        else int.from_bytes(data, "little")
    )


def parse_little_endian(data: bytes) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(data, "little")


def parse_header_flags(data: bytes) -> Record_Header_Flags:
    flag = data[0]
    return Record_Header_Flags(*(bool(flag & bit) for bit in HEADER_FLAGS))


FILE_RECORD_HEADER = (
    (8, 16, parse_little_endian),
    (16, 18, parse_little_endian),
    (18, 20, parse_little_endian),
    (22, 24, parse_header_flags),
    (24, 28, parse_little_endian),
    (32, 38, parse_little_endian),
    (38, 40, parse_little_endian),
    (44, 48, parse_little_endian),
)


def parse_record_header(data: bytes) -> Record_Header:
    return Record_Header(
        *(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in FILE_RECORD_HEADER)
    )


data = b"FILE0\x00\x03\x00\x9dt \x13\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02\x008\x00\x01\x00\xd8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00"
print(parse_record_header(data))
```

```
Record_Header(LogFile_Serial=51860501661, Written=8, Hardlinks=2, Flags=Record_Header_Flags(In_Use=True, Directory=False, Extension=False, Special_Index=False), Record_Size=472, Base_Record=0, Base_Writes=0, Record_ID=65535)
```

Someone told me this is inefficient and unPythonic, and the proper way to do this is to use a combination of `struct` and `ctypes`.

I know I can parse 4 bytes little endian sequences using `struct.unpack("<i", data)[0]`, 4 bytes unsigned LE with this format string: `"<I"`, 8 bytes LE with `"<q"` and 8 bytes ULE with `"<Q"`. But some values are sequences of 6 bytes.

And I don't know how to use `ctypes` structures.

Further MFT uses non-standard formats like Windows File Time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import NamedTuple

EPOCH = datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

def parse_NTFS_timestamp(data: bytes) -> datetime:
    return EPOCH + timedelta(seconds=int.from_bytes(data, "little") * 1e-7)
```

How would one use `ctypes` and `struct` to parse the example I have given, and parse byte sequences containing non-standard encodings for example timestamp fields from 0x10 $STANDARD_INFORMATION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of both `struct` and `ctypes` parsing the data.  Refer to the `struct` [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) and `ctypes` [Structures and unions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions):

```py
import ctypes as ct
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

class RecordHeader(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('pad1', 8 * ct.c_uint8),
                ('LogFile_Serial', ct.c_uint64),
                ('Written', ct.c_uint16),
                ('HardLinks', ct.c_uint16),
                ('pad2', 2 * ct.c_uint8),
                ('Flags', ct.c_uint16),
                ('Record_Size', ct.c_uint32),
                ('pad3', 4 * ct.c_uint8),
                ('_Base_Record_Base_Writes', ct.c_uint64),
                ('pad4', 4 * ct.c_uint8),
                ('Record_ID', ct.c_uint32))

    # ctypes can't handle a 6-byte field.  Read as 8-byte field and parse with
    # properties using bit shifting and masking.
    @property
    def Base_Record(self):
        return self._Base_Record_Base_Writes & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF

    @property
    def Base_Writes(self):
        return self._Base_Record_Base_Writes >> 48

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Display representation of the structure'''
        # Gather relevant fields and values.
        slist = [(k, getattr(self,k)) for k, _ in self._fields_ if not k.startswith('pad')]
        params = ', '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in slist])
        # format the parameters for a nice display.  Add the properties as well.
        return f'RecordHeader({params}, Base_Record={self.Base_Record}, Base_Writes={self.Base_Writes})'

# OP data, but modified to test the Base_Record/Base_Writes fields with something non-zero.
data = b'FILE0\x00\x03\x00\x9dt \x13\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02\x008\x00\x01\x00\xd8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x88\x77\x66\x55\x44\x33\x22\x11\x05\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'

# struct can't handle a 6-byte field either.  Read as an 8-byte field.  Process later as needed.
result = struct.unpack('<8xQHH2xHL4xQ4xL', data)
RHeader = namedtuple('RHeader', 'LogFile_Serial Written HardLinks Flags Record_Size Base_Record_Base_Writes Record_ID')
print(RHeader(*result))

# ctypes Structure example.  Processes the 6-byte/2-byte field.
rh = RecordHeader.from_buffer_copy(data)
print(rh)
print(f'{rh._Base_Record_Base_Writes=:#x} {rh.Base_Record=:#x} {rh.Base_Writes=:#x}')
```

Output:

```
RHeader(LogFile_Serial=51860501661, Written=8, HardLinks=2, Flags=1, Record_Size=472, Base_Record_Base_Writes=1234605616436508552, Record_ID=65535)
RecordHeader(LogFile_Serial=51860501661, Written=8, HardLinks=2, Flags=1, Record_Size=472, _Base_Record_Base_Writes=1234605616436508552, Record_ID=65535, Base_Record=56368583571336, Base_Writes=4386)
rh._Base_Record_Base_Writes=0x1122334455667788 rh.Base_Record=0x334455667788 rh.Base_Writes=0x1122
```

Note that parsing timestamps is another question.  Stick to one at a time on SO.  Ask another question with a *specific* example such as the raw data and the expected result.  Add your coding attempt.

Comment: The timestamp question has already been asked and answered: [Python date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947253/5987)  The code in the question looks almost right, except that it multiplies where it needs to divide.

Comment: I already knew how to parse Windows File Time and my example function gives the correct output. I use multiplication by inverse instead of division because multiplications are faster than divisions. I have decided to make the timestamps `@property` like you did.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Use a time zone-aware utc epoch then display in the time zone you want for accuracy. I added an answer in the [Python date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947253/5987) link.