# Can anyone tell me how can I relate timegettime time with epochtime

Tags: windows, time

I am working on a project where we are collecting data from various sensors and logging various logs.

Mostly all the sensors are logged using `TimeGetTime` in millisecs which is time measured from start time of PC. But I have one sensor that has data logged in epoch time which is in millisecs .

Now how can I relate the epoch time with `TimeGetTime` if I had to synchronize all sensor datas together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to convert the epoch time (I assume it's the number of milliseconds (*ms*) elapsed since [[Wikipedia]: Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or [`([MAN]: time)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html)`* 1000`) to *ms* elapsed since *Win* started, you have to:

1. Get the number of *ms* since *Win* started, using (as you already mentioned) [[MSDN]: timeGetTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx) (as an alternative you could use [[MSDN]: GetTickCount64 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx); I didn't study the difference - in terms of precision - between the 2)
2. Get the current *Win* time, using [[MSDN]: GetSystemTimeAsFileTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Since the time retrieved at previous step is (according to [[MSDN]: FILETIME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx)):

   > a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

   you need to convert it to *Ux* epoch style time. The conversion algorithm is quite straightforward, there are lots of examples on the web, here's one: [[SO]: Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux) (since that result is in seconds, you'll need to multiply it by 1000). This represents the number of *ms* elapsed since *Ux* epoch time, til now
4. By subtracting the value from *Step 1* (*ms* since *Win* started) from the one from *Step 3* (*ms* since *Ux* epoch time), you'll get the number of *ms* between the *Ux* epoch time and the time *Win* started. This is **the offset that you'll have to subtract** from every timestamp that you get from the *funky* sensor, to be in sync with the timestamps got from all the other sensors.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. yes i am trying to call both  _ftime64_s( &timebuffer );   unsigned long lwTime   = timeGetTime();  under a critical section so that there will be not more than 1-2 millisecs difference if there is a difference in execution of the functions ,and then will try looking at the difference between two results at frequent intervals of maybe 20 minutes .

Comment: You're welcome :). That's why I ordered Steps _#1_ and _#2_ to be consecutive so any processing done doesn't influence the result. You can perf test it by adding (duplicating) _#1_ between _#2_ and _#3_, so it will be _#2.5_ if you will. By subtracting _#1_ from _#2.5_, you'd see the time difference between the 2 calls (in _ms_), but Id doubt it's notable (well unless the machine (_CPU_) is heavily loaded by other processes). As long as the app doesn't involve threads, I'm not sure you'd need a critical section.