# Visual Studio 2015/2017 Year 2038 bug with ftime functions

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, year2038

I am migrating some code from vc120 to vc140 and I am running into a problem with ftime64.  The problem is similar to one mentioned on the [Visual Studio dev community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57100/-ftime64-does-not-work-past-the-year-2038.html) where ftime64 seems to have a [year-2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) in 2015/2017 but where 2013 does not.

Here's some example code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sys/timeb.h>
int main()
{
  __timeb64 testTime64;  
  _ftime64(&testTime64);  
  printf("%lld\n", testTime64.time);  
  return 0;
}
```

With dates after 03:14:07 UTC on 2038/01/19, the time appears to wrap over the 32-bit boundary.

To test, compile the above code as ftime_check and run the following from an admin command prompt (note your numbers will vary due to the time of day on your clock):

```
date 1/18/2038 && ftime_check
2147474668
date 1/20/2038 && ftime_check
-2147319812
```

For reference, here is the (expected) output as seen under vc120:

```
date 1/18/2038 && ftime_check
2147482944
date 1/20/2038 && ftime_check
2147655752
```

I see the same issue with all of these functions ftime, _ftime, _ftime64, _ftime_s, and _ftime64_s

**Is anyone else experiencing this, and how are you working around it?**

Comment: You might want to edit this into a [mcve] so we can try it without needing to add the missing bits or set our system clock to 2040 and mess up cookies, certs, licenses and such.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftime-ftime32-ftime64) `_timeb64` should be good through 12/31/3000. How are you arriving at the conclusion that it doesn't work?

Comment: @DaveS - I updated it with some additional steps. You will have to adjust your clock to test this.

Comment: `2526338561` looks a little suspicious as this corresponds to 2050-01-21 00:42:41 UTC.

Comment: @HowardHinnant oops copy/paste fail. Updated post.

Comment: The Y2038 bug is still very much present in Windows. FILETIME is a good example of that.

Comment: It is a simple bug in the common_ftime_s() template function, it has a `static_cast<__time32_t>`, should have been TimeType.  They'll get it fixed, call Microsoft Support if you can't wait.

Comment: That's the plain _ftime64 function in the code above.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date is a cross-platform date/time library that does not have the 2038 bug.  Runs on VS-2015.  I used it to catch your copy/paste fail.  Might be useful for you, might not, you decide.

Comment: Maybe you have `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` defined by some way.

Comment: @HansPassant the interesting thing is the regression from vc120 that hasn't been caught yet. I will have to contact support as this bug causes major problems and doesn't pass contractual tests to guarantee functionality past 2038!  How best to contact them?  I wonder how many pieces of software being written right now will be in use in 2038 and fail unexpectedly (hopefully not many).

Comment: @AndreKampling _USE_32BIT_TIME_T is not defined.

Comment: It ought to be a bit obvious that nobody is using this.  There just isn't much point in using these deprecated posix functions with their non-deprecated name, given that you have to type the underscore.  You might as well use the standard C library function and get it over with.

Comment: @HansPassant it doesn't seem to matter which version of ftime I call, it has the same result. What function do you think should be used instead?

Comment: The standard C library function, time().  time_t is a 64-bit type in the Microsoft CRT.

Comment: @HansPassant we need time in milliseconds, time() is in seconds.

Comment: Do you need local time, or UTC?  `system_clock::now()` will give you time since 1970-01-01 UTC in 1/10 microsecond precision, which you can then easily truncate (or round) to milliseconds, e.g. with `time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now())`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks. It looks like system_clock::now() isn't specified as UTC in the documentation. I do need time in UTC. Also this function is C++11, so I won't be able to use it across all supported platforms at this time, but I may still be able to use it in Windows.

Comment: It's true that the `system_clock` epoch is unspecified.  I'm trying to get it specified (https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r3.html#time.clock.system), and I have the unofficial assurance of the std::lib implementors that they will not move off of this de facto standard in the interim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening an issue with Microsoft Visual Studio support, they have confirmed this as a bug with Universal CRT that can be fixed by using an updated Windows SDK that is slated to release alongside Windows 10 Redstone 3 (aka Fall Creators Update).  An updated UCRT will also be released alongside RS3.

**Update 2018/05/08:** The Fall Creator's Update (1709) fixed this for applications linking dynamically against the CRT (/MD and /MDd). But in order to fix this when linking statically against the CRT (/MT and /MTd), you must change the Target Platform Version to **10.0.16299.0** (or later) and rebuild the application.

The internal bug ID is: **DevDiv.436129 , 437701**

**Workaround options:**

GetSystemTime(SYSTEMTIME *lpSystemTime)
SystemTimeToFileTime(const SYSTEMTIME *lpSystemTime, FILETIME *lpFileTime)

**Requires Windows 8 or above:**
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(FILETIME *lpSystemTimeAsFileTime)

**Convert SYSTEMTIME to FILETIME**
SYSTEMTIME starts in year 1601 while time_t usually starts in year 1970.
To convert to time_t you have to account for the difference in seconds between 1601 and 1970 (See: [Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux#6161842))

Comment: On the upside, the UCRT is shipped as part of the OS, so you don't need to update redistributable components that are bundled with your application.

Comment: But on the downside, you have to force the end-user to install UCRT on the target machine.  Also, if you are linking statically against the runtime (which I am to work around UCRT not being installed on the target machine, ie, Windows 7) you have to update your software deployment to get the fix.