# How to convert milli seconds time to FILETIME in c++

Tags: c++, time, epoch, filetime

I have a time in secs (ex:1505306792).

How to convert this into FILETIME?

Here is the code i have tried

```
    INT64 timer64 = 1505306792;

    timer64 = timer64 *1000 *10000;

    ULONGLONG xx = timer64;

    FILETIME fileTime;
    ULARGE_INTEGER uliTime;

    uliTime.QuadPart = xx;
    fileTime.dwHighDateTime = uliTime.HighPart;
    fileTime.dwLowDateTime = uliTime.LowPart;
```

This result FILETIME is coming as 1648-09-13 15:34:00

I am expecting this date to be 2017-09-13 12:46:31 . I am getting the same when using online converters.

Any idea how to solve this?

I have seen some answers using boost, but it is available in my project.

Comment: One millisecond = 1/1000th of a second. Why are you multiplying by ten million?

Comment: The first filetime converter I looked up (http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=1505306792&inputformat=unix), when you use its default settings and enter 1505306792, you get an output of Wednesday, September 13, 2017 12:46:32pm.  Based on its default, I think you need to focus on the input format being unix.

Comment: There's an epoch difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux

Answer (score 3):

It's about adding 116444736000000000, see [How To Convert a UNIX time_t to a Win32 FILETIME or SYSTEMTIME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-t-to-a-win32-filetime-or-systemtime):

```
   #include <winbase.h>
   #include <winnt.h>
   #include <time.h>

   void UnixTimeToFileTime(time_t t, LPFILETIME pft)
   {
     // Note that LONGLONG is a 64-bit value
     LONGLONG ll;

     ll = Int32x32To64(t, 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
     pft->dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)ll;
     pft->dwHighDateTime = ll >> 32;
   }
```

Comment: Windows uses January 1, 1601 as an epoch? How utterly bizarre.

Comment: Obviously people need spreadsheets that go back that far. And no further.