# How to convert Win32 FILETIME to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, macos, datetime, winapi, time

I am new to objective-C and Mac:

How to convert the **Windows64BitSeconds**  in below to its MacOS NSDate localtime and UTC?.
By some online reading/searching came up with the following, but not sure
if this is correct.

//found some useful code online: [Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-)

```
#define WINDOWS_TICK 10000000
#define SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH 11644473600LL

windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux.
unsigned WindowsTickToUnixSeconds(long long windowsTicks) 
{
    return (unsigned)(windowsTicks / WINDOWS_TICK - SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH);
}

long long Windows64BitSeconds = A 64 Bit Value of type FILETIME;

long long UnixSeconds = WindowsTickToUnixSeconds(Windows64BitSeconds); 
NSDate *srcDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:UnixSeconds];
NSLog(@"srcDate=%@", srcDate);  //What this supposed to display, UTC?.This seems to display local time???

NSTimeZone* localTZ = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone* utcTZ = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger localGMTOffset = [localTZ secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTZ secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = gmtOffset - localGMTOffset;

NSDate* destDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:srcDate];
NSLog(@"destinationDate=%@", destDate);  //What this supposed to display, UTC?.This seems to display Localtime???
```

Not certain abut the above code versus the correct code?.

Comment: This is a good question. I don't think you are far off the correct code.  I would imagine the `srcDate` is in the same timezone as the input Win32 `FILETIME`, so you need to verify that first.

Comment: on the windows side got the local date+time, converted it to int64bit.
On the Mac side used it, assigned the int64 generated at the Windows side to the Windows64BitSeconds as shown in the code.
Observed: 1) srcDate in above was a few hours behind the Windows time.
2)destDate  in above matached the Windows date+time.   I do not
have solid explanation for this observation. Can anyone see what is happening?. Thanks.

Comment: I can only assume time zone.  You should always store/transmit times in UTC and display in local time as necessary.  Either that or the calculation is wrong, however it looks good from the link you provided.