# OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input -11644473600.0 with the unit 's'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timestamp

I am trying to turn that number from a dataframe into a datetime, the column time['date'] looks like the following:

[image]

i tried the following:

```
df1["st_mtime"]=pd.to_datetime(df1["st_mtime"],unit="s")
```

so i am getting below error:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input -11644473600.0 with the unit 's'

I want it to be changed to `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: It is in negative sign.

Comment: if these are seconds since the epoch (Unix time), this would be around the year 1600. However, pandas Timestamp can only go back to `Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux) might help.

Comment: @Pygirl yes its negative time which i am unable to understand how to transform

Comment: @MrFuppeswhat do you suggest , should be done?