# Why is the constant 11644473600 used for converting FILETIME to Unix time?

Tags: time, unix-timestamp, filetime

I've been researching on how different operating systems represent time, as well as how to convert between them. I've read several pages that all describe a similar method for converting between FILETIME and Unix time, most notably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux). The logic behind how this works is pretty simple and plainly states that there's been `11644473600` seconds from `January 1st, 1601` to `January 1st 1970`.

My question is: Why is the constant `11644473600` and not `11644732800`?

When I divide out 11,644,473,600 seconds, that equals 134,774 days. That would include 92 leap years and comes out to ~368.99 years. Every time I run the numbers myself, the number I come out to for 369 years (which would contain 92 leap years) ends up being 11,644,732,800 seconds (134,777 days).

Am I just doing some bits of math wrong or is there some other bits of information that I haven't read or learned about how this conversion works?

EDIT:
As pointed out by Vladimir Posvistelik, my issue was that I wasn't calculating leap years correctly. The years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are NOT leap years. This explains my number being off by three days.

Comment: This looks like a good question, but it doesn't appear to be a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might want to ask this on one of the linux sites instead, e.g. Unix & Linux SE or Super User or Server Fault

Comment: @Brian61354270 I'm not fully agree with you: dates manipulation is a classic programming problem (at some point). As a result, we may find a lot of similar questions on SO.

Comment: I agree, understanding some magic constant used in programming format conversions seems fine as a SO question.  I had a similar conversion issue with one of Microsoft's date formats earlier this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they came from the fact, that not all years divisible by 4 are leap. As said on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year):

> This extra leap day occurs in each year that is an integer multiple of 4 (except for years evenly divisible by 100, but not by 400)

Comment: After reading the wiki page linked in this answer, this was the important piece of the puzzle I was missing. In school they simply said every four years was a leap year. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @Azrael in addition I can recommend the following aggregation of "date-time false assumptions" - FalsehoodsAboutTime.com (which is a shortcut to the original blog post https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)