# How to convert time::Tm to u64 for JWT expiration date

Tags: time, rust, jwt

I'm using the [jwt crate](http://mikkyang.github.io/rust-jwt/doc/jwt/index.html) and I want to set the expiration date in the `Claims` struct. The `exp` field in [`Registered`](http://mikkyang.github.io/rust-jwt/doc/jwt/claims/struct.Registered.html) took a `Option<u64>`.

I can retrieve the current date and add 1 day to it by doing:

```
let mut timer = time::now();
timer = timer + Duration::days(1);
```

but I don't see how to convert this `time::Tm` to a `u64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exp` field is of "NumericDate" type, which according to [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2) is "*number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap seconds.*"

This description is the same as [the `to_timespec` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/struct.Tm.html#method.to_timespec), which "*Convert time to the seconds from January 1, 1970*" in the Tm's current timezone*.

Thus:

```
let mut timer = time::now_utc();
timer = timer + Duration::days(1); 
token.claims.reg.exp = Some(timer.to_timespec().sec as u64);
```

(Note that while `time + duration` always return UTC time as of v0.1.36, it is arguably [a defect](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time/blob/5d71ac97f31380d15af3abfc17618780522a1ad1/src/lib.rs#L342-L352) that could be fixed in a future. To be forward-compatible, I used `now_utc()` instead of `now()`.)

(*: `to_timespec` basically calls `gmtime()` on POSIX and the POSIX standard ignores leap seconds. On Windows it converts the structure to a FILETIME [which again ignores leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130573/does-the-windows-filetime-structure-include-leap-seconds). So `to_timespec` is safe to use if you really care about the 27-second difference.)

---

If you are using `std::time::SystemTime`, the same can be obtained using

```
let mut timer = SystemTime::now();
timer += Duration::from_secs(86400);
token.claims.reg.exp = Some(timer.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs());
```